# Correct way of sending JSON Array payloads via RESTful Web API

Tags: arrays, json, webapi, griddb

I am sending a JSON payload in a web API request, the server expects payload in JSON-Array format.
The data is to be inserted in a GridDB database container.
I have tried sending the data in normal JSON format as well as Array format.
e.g.
`{1,0,1,0,0,67,137,4,15,0,1,1.53,95,13.7,106.6,4.9,99,3.4,2.1,18,0.7,1,3.5,0.5}`

and
`[ {1,0,1,0,0,67,137,4,15,0,1,1.53,95,13.7,106.6,4.9,99,3.4,2.1,18,0.7,1,3.5,0.5}]`

But getting error.

**GridDB Web API** documentation is here:-
[http://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_3/GridDB_Web_API_Reference.html#ロウ登録](http://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_3/GridDB_Web_API_Reference.html#%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A6%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2)

What is the correct JSON Array format for the above data ?

Thanks